# Laravel Mix - Dependency was not found (for custom js file)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm really fracking tired to struggle with mix thing.. really cannot understand what it is.

I just want to add a piece of script that needs to control my AJAX request. So here's what I do.

1. I create custom file `searchResource.js` on `resources\assets\js` directory.
2. Edit `webpack.mix.js` file before to after.

   ```
   // Before
   mix
       .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')

   // After
   mix
       .js([
           'resources/assets/js/app.js',
           'resources/assets/js/searchConcepts.js'
       ], 'public/js')
   ```
3. On console, run `npm run dev`.

After this, I got `Dependency was not found` error and don't have a clue why/where do I specify dependencies for just simple script add.

After extensive search, I think there is something more has to be done but don't know what it is. Further, I believe I can't handle this. Need help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, there is a reason why I can't mix things all together in app.js, but still don't know why. However, I've manage to do this anyway.

First, I should use `.scripts()` method and save my custom script to something like `all.js`, not `app.js`.

So, here is my answer.

```
mix
    .scripts('/resources/assets/js/ajaxAdaptor.js')
    .js('.. ')
```